# What is the safest way to perform backups of my partitions?

Tags: backup

The partitions on my phone are visible on /dev/mts/mtsX, and I'd like to copy the contents of those files onto my sd card for safe keeping. Is it safe to just say:

```
cat /dev/mtd/mtd0 > /sdcard/mtd0
```

Because I'm not so sure if it's safe to use cat on binary files. Maybe there is a port of dd?

Answer (score 1):

`cat` is a very bad idea here. If you really want to make a backup on partition level, rather take a look at [dd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29). What you probably want to do is something like

```
dd if=/dev/mtd/mtd0 of=/sdcard/mtd0.image
```

For more details, you might want to consult the [dd Man Page](http://ss64.com/bash/dd.html). Remark: I'm not sure whether the `dd` shipped with Android supports the full list of options, so you might have to try out.